# dynamically create a resource property in terraform (without knowing the property name in advance)

Tags: terraform, devops

- using terraform version 1.3.5
  I have the following resource:

  resource "kong_service" "se_service" {
  for_each = var.services

  ```
  name = each.value.name
  protocol = each.value.protocol
  host = each.value.host
  port = each.value.port
  retries = each.value.retries
  ```

  }

and the variable definition:

```
variable "services" {
  type = map(any)
}
```

this is an example variables:

```
services = {
  aaa : {
    name: "aaa"
    host     = "aaa.com"
    port     = 8080
    protocol = "http"
    retries  = 5
  },
  bbb : {
    read_timeout    = 3000
    connect_timeout = 1000
    write_timeout   = 2000
    name: "bbb"
    host     = "bbb.com"
    port     = 8080
    protocol = "http"
    retries  = 5
  }
}
```

As you can see, the resource properties, and my *service* variable properties has the same names, let's say the kong_service resource has a lot more fields, I don't want to keep writing those in my main.tf, I want to iterate over each service from variables.tf and just put each service properties as is, inside the resource block as variables dynamically, this way, if a new property is being used which I didn't provide hardcoded in main.tf, it will still be used. couldn't find a way to iterate on the variable fields

This is as an example of what I want to achive at the end:

```
resource "kong_service" "se_service" {
  for_each = var.services

  
  for key,value in each.value
  "${key} = ${value}"
}
```

Comment: Would the keys correspond to the argument names?

Comment: There are a few different paths forward for this, but we need to know the version of Terraform used.

Comment: @MattSchuchard  I edited the last section example, I use each.value not each.key (but i guess u understood this :) ),  I am using terraform version 1.3.5